# How to spread out congested points on a plot (in matplotlib)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

The points on my graph are too tightly packed and I would like to spread them out but still follow the same pattern. I tried to use a step plot but it did not make any difference (see code below).

```
[...]
x = data1[:,0]
y = data1[:,1]

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y,'b.')
plt.title('normal plot')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.figure(2)
plt.step(x,y,'g.')
plt.title('plot with spread out points')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

[image]

[Link to my data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o2-CjtjcX-KEsrweZK8j_Tz65w9dsbGE)

What am I missing in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Spread out" isn't very specific, but if you want to be able to distinguish between points more easily your best option is to change the `markersize`:

```
plt.scatter(x, y,'.b',ms=4)
plt.title('Scatter Plot')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

From there since your data are gathered around the bottom of the plot you can examine those more closely by setting the limits to only focus on those "congested" points:

```
plt.ylim((0,50))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd log scale your y axis. Add this:

`plt.yscale('log')`

Here are examples I've been working on [to show the number of unfiltered diesel fleets at all fleet sizes from ODOT records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iikK1.jpg); datapoints can be randomly dispersed on both x and y axes to spread things out, as the lower plot has. Both are log scaled on the x axis and the bottom y value has no significance.